# Vertically scrollable div with dynamic height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Following is my HTML:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.non-scrollable-container {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.scrollable-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="non-scrollable-container"></div>
  <div class="scrollable-container"></div>
  <div class="scrollable-container"></div>
  <div class="scrollable-container"></div>
</div>
```

Now,  " non-scrollable-container " div is dynamic in height but not scrollable and also it has 100% width.

All three " scrollable-container " div should be set inline and also scrollable individually. I am trying to align them inline but not able to do it. How to set them inline inside flexbox?

Comment: overflow:auto for wrapper should work

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But, I don't want to apply scroll to wrapper. Only scrollable-containers should be scrollable.

Comment: when you say inline - do you mean horizontally aligned?

Comment: @Pete yes. It should be horizontally aligned.

Comment: Thanks, @Pete. But I also tried that. But it is not working.

Comment: define Height and width...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.non-scrollable-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    height:auto;
}

.scrollable-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.scrollable-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width:33.33%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="non-scrollable-container">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable-row">
    <div class="scrollable-container">
      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable-container">
      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable-container">
      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this code.It works for you. 
If you have any problem let me know.

Comment: is it browser compatible? I tried it in Firefox. Everything works fine except it does not show a scrollbar for the scrollable container. And also scrollable container cannot have fixed height.

Comment: It works in mine(firefox browser). Update your firefox and try again.

Comment: It works because you are applying fix height to scrollable-container. But in my case I want it to be dynamic based on the content of non-scrollable-container.

Comment: Yes. It is. Thank you.